# Checking permissions in Liferay Application Display Template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing an application display template (freemarker) for the sitemap portlet to render in my layout in the pages footer. So far everything works. I can iterate through my pages and render the correct result. Checks on whether a page is hidden work as well.

Now I need one more feature. I want to check whether a page is accessible by logged users only (= don't show a link to a guest user when the page permissions forbid guests to see the page).

Here is my ADT code.

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as entry>
        <#assign layoutURL = portalUtil.getLayoutURL(entry, themeDisplay)>

        <div class="grid3">
            <ul>
                <#if entry.isHidden() == false> 
                    <li><a href="${layoutURL}">${entry.getName(locale)}</a></li>
                </#if>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Maybe `${themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker()}` can do the trick but I don't really have a clue on how to check for a users permissions on page. In a perfect world I can distinguish between different user groups but I'd settle for show when logged in, hide when anonymous (=guest).

I'm using Liferay 6.2. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is **to check the view permission for a given page (Layout)**.

Freemarker snippet:

```
layoutPermission.contains(permissionChecker, entry.getPlid(), 'VIEW')
```

`layoutPermission` is available for all ADT templates and references [`LayoutPermission`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/permission/LayoutPermission.java) interface. `entry` means the current `Layout` instance.

I took the advice from [this post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/35656928) on Liferay Forums.

**To simply find out, if the user logged in** you can call [`ThemeDisplay#isSignedIn`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html#isSignedIn()).

Freemarker snippet:

```
<#if themeDisplay.isSignedIn()>
    <#-- user is logged in -->
<#else>
    <#-- user is guest -->
</#if>
```

Comment: I thought of themeDisplay.isSignedIn() as well but does that help with a pages permissions? I don't want to build two seperate navigations but rather one navigation which tages permissions into consideration when iterating thorugh my pages tree. The more simple solution without details permissions still need to recognize that a logged in user is not allowed to see a nav item. Distinguishing between GroupA and GroupB is nice to have but not vital. So basically I need to know if a page is visible to everyone or resticted to logged in users so I can avoid rendering certain links for guest users.

Comment: I think the use of themeDisplay.isSignedIn() might not be the solution because I don't want to exclude a static pages blacklist. I want to set permissions for pages freely by using liferays site administration features.

Comment: You're right. I haven't read the question carefully enough. ThemeDisplay#isSignedIn can only be used to check, whether the user is signed in (or guest). It doesn't evaluate user permissions to individual pages (layouts).

Comment: Perfect. Thats exactly it. Thanks for your help.